# Qt creator 4.1 and cmake

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Whenever I change a `CMakeLists.txt` in my project, Qt Creator keeps re-running cmake.

In previous version to re-run cmake you had to go on the "Project" tab and ask for it by.

Is there a way to revert to the old behaviour and manually relaunch cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck

Tools > Options > Build & Run > CMake > Autorun CMake

for the CMake executable that you use.